# Flask SQLAlchemy relationship makes request very slow

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Flask SQLAlchemy for my project and I realized my customers page is very slow because I am trying to get destination for each customers. My structure looks like this.

```
class Users(db.Model):


    __tablename__ = "users"
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   first_name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
   last_name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
   created_date = db.Column(db.DateTime,nullable=False,default=datetime.datetime.now())
   email  = db.Column(db.Unicode(50), nullable=False)
   account  = db.Column(db.Unicode(10), nullable=False)
   number  = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
   user_type  = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False, default='ADMIN')
   created_by  = db.Column(db.Unicode(10), nullable=False, default='SYSTEM')
   destinations = db.relationship('Destinations', backref="customer",lazy="dynamic")


class Destinations(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'destinations'
    import datetime
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    did = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    gateway = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    channel = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    own = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    number = db.Column(db.Unicode(50), nullable=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    created_by = db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False)
    created_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now())
    expire_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    record = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    auth_did = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    auth_gw  = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
```

In my all customers page, I list all customers which the request if fast but when I try to load all destinations for each customer, the request takes a lot of time for it to load.

```
{% for customer in customers %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{customer.first_name}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.number}}</td>
            <td>
                {% for destination in customer.destinations %}
                    {{destination.number}}<br />
                {% endfor %}
            </td>

            <td>
                {% for destination in customer.destinations %}
                    {{destination.did}}<br />
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
            <td>
                {% for destination in customer.destinations %}
                    {{destination.own}}<br />
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
            <td>

                {% for destination in customer.destinations %}
                    {{destination.created_date|humandatetime|safe}}<br />
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
            <td>

                {% for destination in customer.destinations %}
                    {% if destination.expire_date %}{{destination.expire_date|humandatetime|safe}}{% endif %}<br />
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
            <td>

                {% for destination in customer.destinations %}
                    {{destination.gateway or ''}}<br />
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
            <td>
                {% for destination in customer.destinations %}
                    {{destination.channel or ''}}<br />
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
            <td>
                {% for destination in customer.destinations %}
                    <a href="/customers/destinations/delete/{{destination.did}}/{{destination.id}}">del</a><br />
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
            <td><input type="hidden" value="{{customer.first_name}} {{customer.last_name}}"></td>
            <td><a id="{{customer.id}}" class="user-delete-icon">delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Also the function that get all my customers is this

```
customers = db.session.query(Users).filter_by(user_type='CUST').all()
```

I think the problem is the relationship type lazy but I can't get to fix it

Comment: That's because you've set `destinations` to be `dynamic`. So not only do you have the n+1 problem, you've exacerbated it by executing the query in each loop through `destinations`, so it becomes 8n+1 queries. Why do you believe you need to use `dynamic`?

Comment: Do you mean it is not compulsory I use the lazy=dynamic?

Comment: It is definitely not necessary to use `lazy="dynamic"`. Try `lazy="joined"` instead.

Comment: Okay. I get a better performance when I removed the whole lazy thing. But I will try the lazy=joined.